# How to Statically Link OpenCV with Android AOSP Module?

Tags: android, opencv, android-source

How can OpenCV be built for use by an AOSP module?

The OpenCV4Android project appears to be targeting Java/NDK apps. Native code (within an app) can call OpenCV4Android libraries using C++ [compiled with the NDK](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html).

But when linking the libopencv_core.a with an AOSP C++ module, there are missing references to exception handling code within OpenCV:

```
.../obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopencv_core_intermediates/
libopencv_core.a(array.cpp.o): in function 
cvCreateMatHeader:array.cpp(.text.cvCreateMatHeader+0x13e): 
error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
```

### Does Android Support C++ Exception Handling?

If not, is there a way to compile OpenCV for Android (without use of exceptions)?

Comment: For start, put Android.mk

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Usman.3D I did not.